A highly rated Italian movie about a father and a daughter without a mother
I'm looking for a movie whose IMDb rating is higher than 6.5 and the year of the movie is after 2009. 
It's a relationship of father/daughter and how they live without of a mother. The father is like 40-45 years and the daughter is like 7-8, no older than 10 definetely. The mother has passed away, I can't remember how.
Since she's gone, the father has to take care of his daughter in full time. He prepares her to school, prepares the breakfast, lunch and dinners. He drops her at school and takes her from school with his car. He quits his job and waits till the end of the schoolday at the park nearby. He reads newspapers, eats lunchs at the cafeteria there, talks with other parents. He can't start a new relationship with women because he still thinks of his ex-wife. 

Sounds like Quiet Chaos from 2008.

Pietro is a successful businessman with a wife and a daughter. One day he helps his brother save two women from drowning at the beach. When he returns home he finds that his wife has died. Now Pietro has to take care of his daughter, Claudia. When he drives her to school soon after, he decides to wait for her all day in front of the school, and soon that's what he does every day. He eats at the nearby cafe, gets to know the people who come by and follows from afar the fusion developments at work. Pietro's brother expects him to snap out of it, but who will snap first? 

Starring Nanni Moretti (who also wrote it) and Valeria Golino. Currently rated 6.9 on IMDb. The trailer:




Yes this is it , thank you . I'm sorry i use more than one account because i've deleted my previous accounts due to the cyber attack .
